# Estimating uncertainty in a 3-D grid around the global maximum

Tags: python, statistics, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3-D numpy array with score-values, such that the highest score is the point in space with the highest likelihood of being my solution. The surrounding points will have lower scores. The furthest points from this global maximum will have even lower scores.

In this situation, I would like to estimate which points have values near enough to the global maximum to still be considered statistically meaningful for uncertainty analysis. If, for example, the maximum is 235, the array of the points surrounding the maximum (including the maximum) is as follows:

```
  [[[ 74.,  71.,  74.],
    [ 91.,  95.,  99.],
    [129., 142., 147.]],

   [[162., 161., 159.],
    [228., 235., 232.],
    [153., 159., 160.]],

   [[170., 164., 156.],
    [112., 116., 113.],
    [ 86.,  85.,  85.]]]
```

and the lowest score possible is 13, how can I determine which points to consider near enough in value to be significant? If the scores are above the meaningful threshold, I will expand the search area until I no longer encounter significant data. I have been toying around with a chi-square test, but I'm not sure if this is quite the correct course. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I wonder if 1D clustering would be useful here.  If you just sort the whole set of scores from lowest to highest and there is a cluster around the highest, the points in that cluster might be "close enough".

Comment: One potential solution that I have found is to compute the standard deviation of the entire grid. I can then find the nodes within an acceptable range of the maximum with np.where(grid >= maximum - grid.std()).